# How do I customize Angular Material's input/md-input-container component?

Tags: css, angular-material, pseudo-class

As stated in the title,
how do I customize these elements?
It seems they are using transparent background which is very difficult to view on most background palettes

Answer (score 11):

Add one blank css file after "angular-material.css" and inside that blank css file overwrite the rules you want to customize.

For the problem you are facing I added the following rules in my custom.css.

```
md-input-container.md-default-theme label, 
 md-input-container.md-default-theme .md-placeholder{
    color:grey !important;
}
```

Here you could change `color` or `background-color` as you like.

Comment: Any idea how to change the text color when we type in the input and the line that is under the text when we focus the input ?

Comment: is there any way i can change it for all themes defined instead of mentioning class here md-input-container.md-default-theme

Comment: @Ellone try this  
input.md-input:focus{
    border-color: blue;
  }

Comment: this works, but adjusting the actual theme you're using as suggested by Jean F. is a much better, and supported solution

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend to use the palette configuration:

```
    app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {

        //change default color for primary
        var indigo = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('indigo', {
            '500': '569fd4'
        });
        $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('indigo', indigo);

        //change default color for warn
        var indigo = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('red', {
            '500': 'ff5800'
        });
        $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('red', indigo);

        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('indigo').warnPalette('red');  

        //here you change placeholder/foreground color.
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').foregroundPalette[3] = "rgba(0,0,0,0.67)";

});
```

Source: [How to set light foreground colors for text when using dark theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585716/how-to-set-light-foreground-colors-for-text-when-using-dark-theme)

Comment: hmm, just setting foreground didnt work for me, to get the text to change in inputs, the theme had to use the "dark" setting

Answer (score 0):

To change placeholder color do this, it changes the placeholder color to White:

```
/* do not group these rules */
.your-pre-defined-container > md-input-container > input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #FFF;
}
.your-pre-defined-class > md-input-container > input:-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 4-18 */
    color: #FFF;
}
.your-pre-defined-class > md-input-container > input::-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 19+ */
    color: #FFF;
}
.your-pre-defined-class > md-input-container > input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize Angular Material's input/md-input-container component, you can add this style to your personal style sheet.

```css
md-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  margin: 1px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*
   * The .md-input class is added to the input/textarea
   */ }

   md-input-container .md-input {
     -webkit-order: 2;
         -ms-flex-order: 2;
             order: 2;
     display: block;
     margin-top: 0;
     background: none;
     padding-top: 2px;
     padding-bottom: 2px;
     padding-left: 2px;
     padding-right: 2px;
     border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px ;
     line-height: 26px;
     height: 30px;
     -ms-flex-preferred-size: 26px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     border-style: solid;
     width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     float: left; }

 md-input-container.md-input-focused .md-input,
 md-input-container .md-input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
   padding-bottom: 0;
   border-width: 0 0 2px 0; }

 md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused .md-input {
     border-color: black;
          }


md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused label {
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: green;
          }


md-input-container .md-errors-spacer {
       float: right;
       min-height: 0px;
       min-width: 0px; }
       html[dir=rtl] md-input-container .md-errors-spacer {
         float: left;
         unicode-bidi: embed; }
       body[dir=rtl] md-input-container .md-errors-spacer {
         float: left;
         unicode-bidi: embed; }
       md-input-container .md-errors-spacer bdo[dir=rtl] {
         direction: rtl;
         unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }
       md-input-container .md-errors-spacer bdo[dir=ltr] {
         direction: ltr;
         unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }

 md-icon {
   margin: auto;
   background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   fill: currentColor;
   height: 24px;
   width: 24px;}
   md-icon svg {
     pointer-events: none;
     display: block; }
   md-icon[md-font-icon] {
     line-height: 1;
     width: auto; }

 md-input-container > md-icon {
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   left: 20px;
   right: auto; }





 md-input-container ng-messages, md-input-container data-ng-messages, md-input-container x-ng-messages,
 md-input-container [ng-messages], md-input-container [data-ng-messages], md-input-container [x-ng-messages] {
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   -webkit-order: 4;
       -ms-flex-order: 4;
           order: 4;
   overflow: hidden;
   clear: left; }


 md-input-container ng-message, md-input-container data-ng-message, md-input-container x-ng-message,
 md-input-container [ng-message], md-input-container [data-ng-message], md-input-container [x-ng-message],
 md-input-container [ng-message-exp], md-input-container [data-ng-message-exp], md-input-container [x-ng-message-exp],
 md-input-container .md-char-counter {
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 14px;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.55, 0.2);
   opacity: 1;
   margin-top: 0;
   padding-top: 1px; }

 md-input-container ng-message:not(.md-char-counter), md-input-container data-ng-message:not(.md-char-counter), md-input-container x-ng-message:not(.md-char-counter),
 md-input-container [ng-message]:not(.md-char-counter), md-input-container [data-ng-message]:not(.md-char-counter), md-input-container [x-ng-message]:not(.md-char-counter),
 md-input-container [ng-message-exp]:not(.md-char-counter), md-input-container [data-ng-message-exp]:not(.md-char-counter), md-input-container [x-ng-message-exp]:not(.md-char-counter),
 md-input-container .md-char-counter:not(.md-char-counter) {
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-left: 50px; }


   md-input-container.md-input-focused label:not(.md-no-float), md-input-container.md-input-has-placeholder label:not(.md-no-float), md-input-container.md-input-has-value label:not(.md-no-float) {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0) scale(0.75);
             transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0) scale(0.75); }

  md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid ng-message, md-input-container.md-input-invalid ng-message, md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid data-ng-message, md-input-container.md-input-invalid data-ng-message, md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid x-ng-message, md-input-container.md-input-invalid x-ng-message, md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid [ng-message], md-input-container.md-input-invalid [ng-message], md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid [data-ng-message], md-input-container.md-input-invalid [data-ng-message], md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid [x-ng-message], md-input-container.md-input-invalid [x-ng-message], md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid [ng-message-exp], md-input-container.md-input-invalid [ng-message-exp], md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid [data-ng-message-exp], md-input-container.md-input-invalid [data-ng-message-exp], md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid [x-ng-message-exp], md-input-container.md-input-invalid [x-ng-message-exp], md-input-container.md-default-theme.md-input-invalid .md-char-counter, md-input-container.md-input-invalid .md-char-counter {
     color: rgb(255,44,0);
          }
```