# How can I change the font to be the lighter color in angularjs material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm finding that the color that's being used for the email/password text is hard to read (seems easier on this image...), I'd like to use the lighter whitish grey, how can I modify the code to do this?

[image: screenshot of the color problem]

```
<!-- index.html -->
<md-toolbar layout="row">
<div class="md-toolbar-tools" layout="columns" ng-include="'views/login/login.html'"></div>
</md-toolbar>

<!-- login.html -->
<form name="login" layout="" style="font-size: 0.7em">
<md-input-container>
    <label for="email">email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required/>
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container>
    <label for="password">password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required/>
</md-input-container>
<md-checkbox id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" aria-label="remember me">remember me</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: don't use the `md-accent` CSS class?

Comment: @Claies no that just makes it red when you click on it

Comment: adding those  classes was an attempt to fix it, I just liked the effect.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917263/how-do-i-customize-angular-materials-input-md-input-container-component/29054612#29054612

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too, in the lables and inputs put the class and style, color white, #FFFFFF

```
<md-input-container>
    <label for="email"class="md-body-2" style="color: #FFFFFF !important;">email</label>
    <input class="md-body-2" style="color: #FFFFFF !important;" id="email" name="email" type="email" required/>
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container>
    <label class="md-body-2" style="color: #FFFFFF !important;" for="password">password</label>
    <input class="md-body-2" style="color: #FFFFFF !important;" id="password" name="password" type="password" required/>
</md-input-container>
<md-checkbox id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" aria-label="remember me">remember me</md-checkbox>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to change input text and label colors?
You can do it this way:

```
input {
    color: white !important;
}

label {
    color: white !important;
}

md-input-container .md-input{
    border-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: That will affect the color permanently (i.e. across all themes) , and not just for the current theme.